# Windows Update and Defender have been disabled by malware (Windows 7 x64)

Tags: windows-7, malware

I get the following error when I try to run windows update and the windows update service does not appear in the list of services.

```
Windows Update cannot currently check for updates, because the service is not running. You may need to restart your computer.
```

I have downloaded and run a full scan with malware bytes in safe mode but that hasn't fixed the issue.

I also downloaded the windows update stand-alone installer (Windows6.1-KB947821-v22-x64.msu) and got the following error when I tried to run it:

```
Installer encountered an error: 0x80070424
The specified service does not exist as an installed service.
```

I am also missing the wuausrv registry key.

```
Under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services I have the following:
...
WSearchIfxPi
WudfPf
WUDFRd
...
```

Comment: May be 'sfc /SCANNOW' will help?

Comment: Did you check the services? Is the service installed? Is it running? I believe it is called wuauserv.

Comment: Show contents of registry key `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\wuauserv]`

Comment: The service is not installed or running. I ran sfc and it told me I didn't have any integrity errors

Comment: The wuauserv registry key is missing. I don't see it in regedit.

Comment: @grigriforce - Your Windows registry is corrupt in that case.

Comment: @Ramhound Is it worth it to try fixing or should I just bite the bullet and re-install windows?

Comment: @grigriforce I would try Hitman Pro (its a definite contender for MBAM) http://www.surfright.nl/en/home/

Comment: @Simon: Except MBAM has a free version that's not a trial.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes I know I have used it for a number of years

Answer (score 1):

An automatic FixIt for Windows update is available on Microsoft's Knowledge Base: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058

Personally I'd scan any such compromised system with the Avira boot CD: http://www.avira.com/en/download/product/avira-antivir-rescue-system

Also consider rebuilding (reinstalling everything). Since you can't really be sure to have removed every problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to delete (or rename to be safe) c:\windows\softwaredistribution\datastore\logs\edb.log  and then reboot and try

Comment: That had no effect. I get the same error after renaming the file and rebooting.

Comment: Please try the Microsoft malware removal tool from here: http://www.microsoft.com/security/pc-security/malware-removal.aspx   run the FULL scan.

Comment: Strange question, but what graphic card do you use? If ATI, try uninstall the Catalyst, reboot and seeing if this fixes it

Comment: Also try the fix for Windows Update by re-isntalling it via this program http://www.thewindowsclub.com/downloads/Fix%20WU.zip  (I have not tested this)

Comment: And lastly, can you do a Windows Restore (and if so , delete the .log file as per my first suggestion after the Restore)?